# Material UI floating label

Tags: reactjs, label, material-ui

Did anyone find a solution for the material UI and React textfield not automatically floating label [image: example]. Thanks This is the component I am using it in, the key is passes via Redux from another component and the main data is coming from the localStorage. The result is the same in both Firefox and Chrome  :

```
class UpdateForm extends Component {
  state = {
    dataTask: ''
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.selectedTask !== null) {
      const selectedTaskData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.props.selectedTask));
      this.setState({dataTask: selectedTaskData});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="rootComponent">
        <form className="textFields">
          <div className="rowFieldsUpdate">
            <TextField className="fieldUpdate"
              data-testid="update-id"
              label="ID"
              value={this.state.dataTask.ID}
            />
            <TextField className="fieldUpdate"
              data-testid="update-Username"
              label="Username"
              value={this.state.dataTask.username}
            />
            <TextField className="fieldUpdate"
              data-testid="update-lastname"
              label="Last Name"
              value={this.state.dataTask.lastName}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="rowFieldsUpdateSecond">
            <TextField className="fieldUpdate"
              data-testid="update-firstname"
              label="First Name"
              value={this.state.dataTask.firstName}
            />
            <TextField className="fieldUpdate"
              data-testid="update-email"
              label="Email"
              value={this.state.dataTask.email}
            />
          </div>
          <UpdateDialogWindow />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    selectedTask: state.updateStates.selectedTask
  };
};
```

Comment: Add some code...

Comment: Could you please provide some code where you have implemented textfield component.

Comment: I updated it :)

Comment: I don't know about the material-ui problem, but if you want to use a floating label with generic HTML input you can have a look at this library [react-styled-floating-label](https://github.com/ihor/react-styled-floating-label).

Comment: Is this bug fixed in the current version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a weird material-ui bug. There seems to be a bug where if the initial value of a TextField is set to `undefined` or `null` instead of an empty string (or some other string value), it results in this strange problem. You could try setting your initial state to the following instead:

```
state = {
    dataTask: {
        ID: ''
        username: ''
        ... rest of your fields
    }
}
```